# Android: make a scrollable custom view

Tags: android, view

I've rolled my own custom view and can draw to the screen alright, but what I'd really like to do is set the measuredHeigh of the screen to, say, 1000px and let the user scroll on the Y axis, but I'm having problems doing this.  Can anyone help?

Here's some code:

```
public class TestScreen extends Activity  {
     CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
         mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
         setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
     }
 }
```

and

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setMinimumHeight(1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(...);
        // more drawing
    }
}
```

I've tried to override scrollTo, scrollBy, awakenScrollBars etc with a call to super but to no avail.  Am I missing something silly, or am I making some fundamental mistake?

Thank you in advance,

Martyn

Addition:

I've tried to add this as a custom component with the below layout file and changed the code in `TestScreen` to point at the correct resource with `setContentView(R.layout.exampleLayout)`, but this causes the emulator to crash. I tried commenting the code down to the bare minimum and it still crashes, so there's something fundamentally wrong that I'm doing but I'm not sure what it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <com.martyn.testApp.CustomDrawableView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             />
       </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put your view in a ScrollView!

Note that the ScrollWiew should be the root node
(here it's your LinearLayout)

Comment: This was the method I took eventually.  I have a LinearLayout as the base node in the layout xml, then a Scrollview with my custom view contained within

Comment: @Moons I have a Linear Layout within my scroll view but when I add an image view it does appears in the scroll but when I add my custom view to it, it doesn't..but it does shows when I set my view as the content view of my activity it just shows my view ...so that works...then why does not it work in a scroll view ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do scrolling on your own, you can use a [`Scroller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) and a [`VelocityTracker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) while overriding the `onTouchEvent` method of your custom view. To help you implement it I recommend looking through the Javadocs of these classes and taking a look at android widgets implementations that do scrolling like the [NumberPicker](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java).

Answer (score 6):

If you are wanting the entire activity to be a ScrollView, then do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scrollBody"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/string1" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/string2" />

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Then the activity that uses this layout can look something like this:

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.scroll_layout);
    }
}
```

This assumes that the name of your xml file is scroll_layout.xml.