# Need help regarding design in android Recyclerview, NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to create design like attached image.
i have marked numbers on some widgets in green color in attached image.

point 1: its timing, when i scroll this horizontally then i want to move other RecyclerView items.

point 2: how to club 2 items in recyclerView and show border. (or i have to do this in ScrollView/NestedScrollView?)

point 3: how to make size of recyclerview item that matches the time frame of point 1.

point 4: these items are only vertically Scrollable.

[image: attachment]

Comment: I wrote something like this a while ago using a custom layout manager, but it took 3 days of trial and error for it to show and then another week of actually getting it right. Consider rendering these items to canvas and handling touch events yourself by creating a custom view, instead of RecyclerView.

Comment: can you guide me further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886515/2413303 has the right idea

Answer (score 1):

It should be done by using both side scrollable TableLayout.
[Vertical and Horizontal scroll table view with custom data](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView)

Comment: yes its near to my requirements. :)